# Ejecutar un query cada hora con php

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente query

```
$query = "UPDATE cat_marca as tabla_c
   SET tabla_c.precio = (SELECT tabla_c.precio * tabla_b.porcentaje
                         FROM   cat_concepto as tabla_a
                         INNER  JOIN cat_depreciacion as tabla_b 
                                  ON tabla_a.id_depreciacion =  tabla_b.id
                         WHERE   tabla_c.id_concepto = tabla_a.id_concepto)
WHERE  tabla_c.nombre_marca = 'neffos'"
```

necesito  que se ejecute cada hora.

Comment: A menos que pretendas tener el navegador ejecutando la tarea indefinidamente, cosa nada recomendable, se trata de un tema de sistemas, no de programación. Debes especificar, al menos, que sistema operativo tienes instalado.

Comment: Tal como dice Fly comentanos que sistema operativo tenes, en Windows por ejemplo podes usar las tareas programadas o programas como System Scheduler donde creas una tarea especificando cuando cada cuanto tiempo queres que se ejecute y a que archivo tiene que llamar, en este caso metes es consulta en un archivo y creas una tarea que lo llame cada una hora etc. yo tengo creado uno que envia mails todos los dias a las 23:59 asi que solo cree la tarea y lo deje corriendo y todos los dias a esa hora se ejecuta solo. Danos un poco mas de info para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: cuento con windows 10